# Search for dictionaries with enum as key

Tags: c#, resharper

I'd like to search a large set of code for any usage of an `Enum` as a key for a dictionary.  Is there a pattern I can use with resharper's "Search with pattern" that would find all such occurrences?

Comment: `\[MyEnumName\..*\]` (if search with pattern uses regexes, I can't remember)

Comment: It's not a specific enum I'm looking for, just any dictionary with any enum key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a pattern like:

`new Dictionary<$t$, $t2$>()`

and set both `t` and `t2` placeholders to be types. Then set `t` to be System.Enum or derived type. This will find all instantiations of a dictionary with an enum as the key.

Also, if you have ReSharper 8, you can put the text caret on either TKey or TValue in code such as:

`var d = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>()`

and invoke the Navigate To menu (Ctrl+Shift+G in intellij scheme) and select Go to Generic Substiutions. You'll then see a tree results view with a list of all substitutions (e.g. MyEnum here and any other type that's used in the key). Expanding those nodes will show usages. See here for more: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/06/navigation-improvements-resharper-8/

Comment: Nice, that works, I just had to change it to `new Dictionary<$t$, $t2$>($args)`

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be text code? It would be trivial to do with reflection if you can do this on the compiled code (if the code still builds), unless you need to search for it within methods too in which case it's a bit harder.

Comment: Well I don't want to find them at runtime, I want to find them in the code source so I can identify/address possible GC issues.  And its entirely possible they could be contained inside methods.

Comment: I understand you don't want to find them at runtime, the question is can you find it (now, at design time) by making an application that will reflect over your compiled code & give you the result as text so that you can fix the actual source, or do you need something that works on the source as text itself. If you can afford to compile => run this through a program that will do reflection => see the result & fix manually, then reflection sounds like the best way. If you need to check Inside methods it's harder because you don't get access to the code Inside methods with reflection

Comment: However there are still options (by using mono.cecil) so if it's of interest to you i can try to dig some old code i had that makes use of it if i can find it again

Comment: I suppose I could... the code does compile just fine.  I was hoping for a resharper solution, but I guess reflection could work as long as it's not a huge hassle to set up.